# Is it possible to determine norm of elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra

let R be an integral domain and I be an ideal of R generated by two elements. say I=(x,y)

we already know if there exists an element z in ring of integers such that N(z)=N(I) (right side is a norm of ideal), then I is a principal ideal.

Question : Given only an ideal I.
If we don't want to I is a principal ideal, then How to determine a z is not in ring of integers?

Suppose R is not a PID
Then we can choose two elements p,q such that (p,q) is not a principal ideal. How to choose? (existence of p and q is already known)

Comment: Do you mean to ask **If I is not principal, then how to find z such that N(z)=N(I) while z is not in the ring of integers**? I am not very sure of what you are asking.

Comment: sorry, I want to show how to choose p and q such that (p,q) is not principal ideal. And How to show that I is not a principal ideal. If we can show that N(z) is not equal to N(I), then we know I is not principal. but we cannot check all of z in ring of integer. So how to show I is not principal? ,in general

Answer (score 0):

I am responding to the question in the comment, which is too long to fit into a comment.
In different cases there are different methods of showing the non-principalness of an ideal, e.g. $I=(x,y)\subseteq\mathbb Q[x,y]$ is not a principal ideal, by degree considerations, for example.
Also, even if you cannot check all $z$ in the ring of integers, you can still prove that such $z$ that $\operatorname{N}(z)=\operatorname{N}(I)$ cannot exist:
Let $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5}).$ Then the norm of $I$ is equal to $|R/I|=|\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z|=2$ (try to prove that $R/I\cong\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ by considering the homomorphism $\mathbb Z\rightarrow R/I:1\mapsto(1+I)$ and noticing that $2\in I$). But there is no element $z$ with norm $2,$ as $\operatorname{N}(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2\not=2, \forall a, b\in\mathbb Z.$
In other cases there are other ways to show a certain ideal is not principal, but I haven't come across with a universal way of doing so.

Hope this provides a hint to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to think more

Comment: Can we calculate a norm of element in cyclotomic field?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Q(i)$ is a cyclotomic field, and its norm is simply $\operatorname{N}(a+bi)=a^2+b^2.$ Other cyclotomic fields' norms might be calculated similarly.

Comment: If degree is large, then I think that it is hard to calculate norm of element.